# Relativeview 5 buttons, don't understand my mistake

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make myself an app to track my progress at the gym since it's one of my new year resolution... I don't go to the gym, and I figure that if I can track progress, i could have some interest in going back.

Here's my issue:

I'm doing my main layout right now, and I want one large button that says: Start workout.
I would like to have 4 buttons centered next to each other with some spaces between each other and the four together would have the form of a square.

I wrote this code, and nothing is working at all right now. I just don't even know where to look anymore. I know I could use LinearLayout but I read everywhere that RelativeLayout should be prioritize

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

<Button 
android:id="@+id/start_workout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:hint="@string/start_workout" 
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/log_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:hint="@string/log_button"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/progress_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:hint="@string/progress_button"
/>  

<Button
android:id="@+id/cardio_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calendar_button"
android:layout_below="@id/progress_button"
android:hint="@string/cardio_button"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/calendar_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardio_button"
android:layout_below="@+id/log_button"
android:hint="@string/calendar_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you share a picture of the desired result? Shuld the five buttons be stacked vertically or should they appear in a horizontal row? Do you want a central one and four stitched at its sides?

Comment: Try setting the attributes of the RelativeLayout to:
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: I want a central one on top and four little square in the middle of the screen 2x2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is.

The first button is screen wide and top aligned.

The other four occupy each 1/4th the screen width and are all below the top one

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_workout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start workout"
        android:textSize="12sp"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/start_workout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cardio_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cardio"
            android:textSize="12sp"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/progress_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Progress"
            android:textSize="12sp"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendar_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Calendar"
            android:textSize="12sp"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/log_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Log"
            android:textSize="12sp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this,but better to use linear layout in your case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cardio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/log_button"
        android:hint="cardio_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/progress_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/log_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/log_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardio_button"
        android:hint="progress_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cardio_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cardio_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardio_button"
        android:hint="calendar_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/log_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_workout"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progress_button"
        android:hint="log_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_workout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="start_workout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```